# Is it possible to use SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name = 'value' where 'value' might appear in more than one row?

Tags: sql, jtable, h2

I am trying to create a screen that will display the history of purchases from a particular customer. My 'Sales' table contains columns "TicketNumber", "CustomerID", "InventoryNo", "Description", "Cost", "Retail", "IndividualSubTotal", "IndividualTax", "IndividualTotal", "SaleSubTotal", "SaleTax", and "SaleTotal".

For the purposes of this screen, I will only need (for now) "TicketNumber", "CustomerID", "InventoryNo", "Retail", "IndividualTax", and "IndividualTotal".

Right now, I am trying to pull the information in by the customer's ID. My ultimate goal is to place the ticket number in the table, but I only want it to appear ONCE. I think I will be able to figure this out. But right now, this is the problem I'm having.

```
    try {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:./RetailApplicationDatabase;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE");

        String sql;
        Statement stmt;

        sql = "SELECT distinct TicketNumber FROM Sales WHERE CustomerID = '" + CustomerNoNumberLabel.getText() + "';";
        stmt = connection.createStatement();

        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) TicketNumberTable.getModel();
        String TicketNumber;

        while(results.next()) {
            TicketNumber = results.getString("TicketNumber");

            model.insertRow(TicketNumberTable.getRowCount(), new Object[] {TicketNumber});
        }
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ViewHistoryDialog.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

As you can see, while there are more results, I want to continue inserting a row into my table. CustomerID will appear in as many different item and ticket numbers that the customer has.

When I compile the program, I am not getting an errors in the output log, but I am not seeing anything being put into the table. I thought it might have been the order that I was trying to do things in, so for now, I have a button on this dialog that says "Load", and when that is pressed, the code above runs.

Where is my problem? Why am I not seeing anything being added to the table?

Thank you in advance for any helpful responses.

EDIT (01/28/2015 - 8:03 AM MST): The sale has already been added to the 'Sales' table within the database. Let's say the customer purchased inventory numbers 1, 2, and 3, and they are the first customer to make a purchase, so the ticket number is 1. Three rows are added to the 'Sales' table, for each inventory number, and the TicketNumber column will have a value of '1' in all three rows. I am then trying to retrieve this information and display it in a jTable. I want to display the ticket numbers in the jTable TicketNumberTable. But my ResultSet is not retrieving the ticket numbers.

EDIT (01/28/2015 - 8:11 AM MST): I changed the code to pull in distinct values for TicketNumber. However, this is not my primary concern, as I am still working on getting my ResultSet to retrieve information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little vague on inserting the ticket number only once.  Does this mean for a given customer?  Or for all customers?  If the latter, you should enforce this as a unique constraint on `TicketNumberTable`.

Second, you can do the `select` and `insert` in a single statement.  There is no need to run multiple queries and do looping.  Something like:

```
INSERT INTO TicketNumberTable(TicketNumber)
    SELECT distinct TicketNumber
    FROM Sales
    WHERE CustomerID = '. . .';
```

Or perhaps:

```
INSERT INTO TicketNumberTable(TicketNumber)
    SELECT distinct TicketNumber
    FROM Sales
    WHERE TicketNumber NOT IN (SELECT TicketNumber FROM TicketNumberTable) AND
          CustomerID = '. . .';
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear on that. The sale has already been added to the 'Sales' table within the database. Let's say the customer purchased inventory numbers 1, 2, and 3, and they are the first customer to make a purchase, so the ticket number is 1. Three rows are added to the 'Sales' table, for each inventory number, and the TicketNumber column will have a value of '1' in all three rows.

I am then trying to retrieve this information and display it in a jTable. I want to display the ticket numbers in the jTable TicketNumberTable. But my ResultSet is not retrieving the ticket numbers.

Comment: @RyanShukis . . . The `select distinct` query should solve the half of your problem about not getting duplicates.  I'm not sure about the jtable piece.

Comment: Okay, I changed that code. But I am still not seeing anything in my jTable. That's my primary problem, at the moment. Thank you for your assistance, however.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I determined the issue... And no one would have been able to see it... I did a SQL Query directly within the H2 console. When the table displayed, I noticed that my CustomerNo column contained a " " (space) before the number. This is because I was using a substring to extract the customer number, and the substring was off by one character, which was the space. I would have never noticed it, had I not gone deeper into it and started analyzing.

Thank you to everyone who has helped me out. Take care.